Comedy Movie with a Jewish Husband and a Black Wife
I want the title of this movie. There was a commercial in a movie "about a new movie that will come to theaters" that says "Nobody can stop them! Jew Husband and Black Wife." Wife will kill everybody while Jewish husband makes calculations and math problems etc.
Another scene that I remember: Another commercial in the movie says "Take care of your wife, or Jumbo will take care of her" and in the scene, some black dude (sorry for that) crashes the wall and takes the woman out. :)
Do you remember the title of this comedy movie ?
Year I think is 70'-90'... I think the movie was released in 1980 or something...

Kentucky Fried Movie contained both of these scenes.

The Kentucky Fried Movie is a 1977 American anthology comedy film directed by John Landis.
The film's writers were the team of David Zucker, Jim Abrahams, and Jerry Zucker, who went on to write and direct Airplane!, Top Secret!, and the Police Squad! television series and its film spinoffs, The Naked Gun films. The "feature presentation" portion of the film stars Evan C. Kim and hapkido Grand Master Bong Soo Han.

The first scene is about Cleopatra Schwartz and the second is about Big Jim Slade. Here's Cleopatra and her rabbi husband [Warning: Contains Nudity], and here's Big Jim [Warning: Slightly Racy]:




A true modern classic. "Fistful of Yen" being another excellent sequence from that movie.
